# How to know which LayoutParams class to use when creating a View programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-layoutparams

Every `ViewGroup` class implements a nested class that extends `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`. So we `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` etc.

Suppose I want to create a `View`, e.g. `TextView` programmatically. I will have to give it the *required* properties, like `layout_width` and `layout_height`, for which I will have to use a `LayoutParams` class. How will I know which `LayoutParams` class to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're putting it into.  If you're putting it into a linear layout, use LinearLayout.LayoutParams.  For relative, use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

If you don't know the type-  add it first via add, then use getLayoutParams to get it.  Then change the layourparams.  When you use the add() that doesn't take a params, the parent will make one for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need view width and height, use a ViewGroup.LayoutParams, as all the other ones inherit from this one. You can assign a ViewGroup.LayoutParams where a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, LinearLayout.LayoutParams, ... is expected.